# Creating new instance based on the Generic Type in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, interface, factory-pattern

I am using Factory patterns, wherein, based on the interface it will create and return the new concreate object.I am using Generic Type and checking it using switch for different concreate objects. Here's my class layout.

```
public class Factory<T>
{
     public T Instance()
     {
         switch(T)
         {
             case IUser:
                return new Domain.User();
                break;
             case IProduct:
                return new Domain.Product();
                break;
         }
     }
}
```

However this throwing me an error:

```
'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

and

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Domain.User' to 'T'
```

and this is how my client code is calling the above Factory class.

```
private readonly Factory<IUser> factory = new Factory<IUser>();
IUser oUser = factory.Instance();
```

Comment: What is the point of this factory?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are trying to accomplish; generics are supposed to work with any type at all, and you have defined one that apparently only works for specified types, which seems contradictory. Returning new classes with no initialization parameters is very strange as well. It would really help if you explained what you plan to use `Factory` for; for example what would you expect `var f = new Factory<MyCustomClass>()` to do?

Comment: sorry my mistake, actually my client code would be like this:
private readonly Factory<IUser> factory;
IUser oUser = factory.Instance();
So that i will have access to the User Domain object, and i would not be having to create new object in client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use type in a `switch`, but you can switch on type name:

```
switch(typeof(T).Name) {
    case nameof(IUser):
        return new Domain.User();
        break;
    case nameof(IProduct):
        return new Domain.Product();
        break;
}
```

Note that this is a pretty inflexible solution, because adding new types to the factory requires a recompile of the fine containing the `switch`.

A better approach is to make a registry of types accepted by the factory, or use an existing solution for it, such as autofac.

Here is a skeletal implementation of a factory with registration:

```
class Factory {
    private readonly IDictionary<Type,Func<object>> registry = new Dictionary<Type,Func<object>>();
    public void Register<T>(Func<T> make) {
        registry.Add(typeof(T), () => (object)make());
    }
    public T Instance<T>() {
        return (T)registry[typeof(T)]();
    }
}
```

You would use the factory as follows:

```
Factory f = new Factory();
f.Register<IUser>(() => new User());
f.Register<IProduct>(() => new Product());
IUser u = f.Instance<IUser>();
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/zXa2wW)

Comment: Thanks, however could you please explain this (A better approach is to make a registry of types accepted by the factory) with an example.

Comment: and how my client code will create the object of the concreate class based on the interface.

Comment: So you mean, i should register all the types on application start and then  create the instance as needed, right? and also i have interface for which i need a new instance of the concreate class, how i could achieve that?

Comment: Actually my intention is to avoid new instance creation from the client code, but per you suggestion, it will create the new instance on the client end only

Comment: @Abbas You would register everything upfront, and then use the factory. The factory does *not* create instances upfront though, these are `Func` objects that get invoked as needed.

Comment: @Abbas Note that registration does not have to be done by the client, it could be done by a special module that instantiates your factory. This way the clients would be shielded from knowledge of the specific types (`User`, `Product`) and would be able to work only with interfaces (`IUser`, `IProduct`). Registration could be performed as part of factory initialization. For example, you could make `static Factory Instance { get { /* instantiate and cache the instance on first use*/ } }` property for accessing `Factory` from the client code.

Comment: This sounds awesome, just  one thing, if you could show me that factory property creation and registering the types there, would be great.

Comment: @Abbas I updated the demo at the link to show the change. Note that I renamed `Instance<T>` method to `Create<T>`, because there's a static member called `Instance`.

Comment: Did you meant, since it's a static property, it will remain in the memory and hence will work as a cache?

Comment: @Abbas In my demo implementation the cached value is `instance` (lower case). Only the `Factory` instance is cached; instances produced by the factory, though, are not cached - you get a brand-new instance every time you call `Create` (assuming that registered `Func`s return new instances, of course).

Comment: Would it be good practice to cache the objects produced from factory, for further use within the life of application, or having the same object is ok too?

Comment: @Abbas This depends only on your requirements. In fact, libraries such as autofac let you decide if caching should be applied or not on the type-by-type basis.